# Filter measure based on value 2 relations away

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm creating a dashboard for an IT Servicedesk based on data from the API of the TOPdesk SaaS Platform. I'm now trying to create 5 measures, which measure the % of the SLA (Service Level Agreement) targets reached. There are 5 types of Service Levels in the Service Level Agreement:

1. Prio-1
2. Prio-2
3. Vragen (= Questions)
4. Standaard wijzigingen (= standard changes)
5. Niet standaard wijzigingen (= non standard changes)

Each Service Level has a target response time and a target solve time, therefore we have 2 measures with each Service Level: one for the response time and one for the solve time.

I've already created a measure (in table 'Incidents') for the response and solve time:

```
% Response SLA = 
DIVIDE(
    COUNTROWS(FILTER(Incidents, NOT(ISBLANK(Incidents[responseTargetDate])) && NOT(ISBLANK(Incidents[responseDate])) && Incidents[responseDate] <= Incidents[responseTargetDate])),
    COUNTROWS(FILTER(Incidents, NOT(ISBLANK(Incidents[responseTargetDate]))))
)
```

and

```
% Solve SLA = 
DIVIDE(
    COUNTROWS(FILTER(Incidents, NOT(ISBLANK(Incidents[slaTargetDate])) && NOT(ISBLANK(Incidents[completionDate])) && Incidents[completionDate] <= Incidents[slaTargetDate])),
    COUNTROWS(FILTER(Incidents, NOT(ISBLANK(Incidents[slaTargetDate]))))
)
```

These measures work. But now I want to filter these measures based on the applied Service Level. In this way, my company can see how well they do with Prio-1 incidents, Prio-2 incidents and so on... Unfortunately, I can't figure out a way to filter these measures on the Service Levels. I'll show my datamodel below, including the relations between these models:

[image: The 3 tables which we rely on and their relations are marked in red and blue]

To summarize my problem: the given measures are nested in the 'Incidents' table. I wish to filter these measures for each Service Level, which are stored in the 'Services' table under the column 'name'. So I want to create 5 measures, one for each Service Level ('Services'[name]).

I've tried the following code, without success:

```
% Response SLA Prio-1 = 
CALCULATE(
    DIVIDE(
        COUNTROWS(
            FILTER(
                Incidents, 
                NOT(ISBLANK(Incidents[responseTargetDate])) && 
                NOT(ISBLANK(Incidents[responseDate])) && 
                Incidents[responseDate] <= Incidents[responseTargetDate]
            )
        ),
        COUNTROWS(FILTER(Incidents, NOT(ISBLANK(Incidents[responseTargetDate]))))
    ),
    Services[name] = "Prio-1"
)
```

I just can't seem to find a way. My DAX knowledge is really fresh, so I'm not an expert at applying these deep relations. I hope somebody can help me out.

Comment: As your set-up currently stands, fields from the *Services* table cannot filter the *Incidents* table. Try changing the cross-filter direction to **Both** for the relationship between the *Incidents* and *IncidentDurationBlocks* tables and also for that between the *Services* and *IncidentDurationBlocks* tables.

Comment: It's probably better to invoke bidirectionality using `CROSSFILTER` in `CALCULATE`, rather than change the behavior of these relationships "permanently".

Comment: @JosWoolley Thanks for your input! It seems to solve my problem indeed.

Comment: @Marcus That indeed seems like a good plan for integrity. Could you help me on my way with implementing crossfilter in my calculate formula?